# How can I set default value for a many2one field in odoo 9?

Tags: default-value, many-to-one, odoo-9

I am new with Odoo-9.0c system and try to make some change to support the work. But I don't know how to set a specific value for many2one field ((selection type). The field also has been created through a custom module. what is the right way to solve this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the new api, just specify which field attribute to change:

```
field_name = fields.Many2one(default=a_function)
```

From [Odoo new api guide line](http://odoo-new-api-guide-line.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html3)

> > > #### Field inheritance
> > >
> > > One of the new features of the API is to be able to change only one attribute of the field:
> > >
> > > ```
> > > name = fields.Char(string='New Value')
> > > ```
> > >
> > > ## ...
> > >
> > > #### Fields Defaults
> > >
> > > Default is now a keyword of a field:
> > >
> > > You can attribute it a value or a function
> > >
> > > ```
> > > name = fields.Char(default='A name')
> > > ```
> > >
> > > ## or
> > >
> > > ```
> > > name = fields.Char(default=a_fun)
> > > ```
> > >
> > > ## ...
> > >
> > > ```
> > > def a_fun(self):  
> > >     return self.do_something()
> > > ```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to use something dynamic you can define a function which will set the default for the field in your record. In your function you will need to identify the id of the record on your related model and assign the value of your field to that id.

```
@api.multi
def _get_field_name_default(self):
    related_model_id = self.env['related.model'].search([<YOUR DOMAIN HERE>]).id
    return related_model_id

field_name_id = fields.Many2one('model.name', string="Field Title", default=_get_field_name_default)
```

If this value is expected to alway be the same and you already know that id of the record in your related model then you could assign it statically.

```
field_name_id = fields.Many2one('model.name', string="Field Title", default=1)
```

Better to use a function which is capable of returning False or None in the event the record on your related model has been removed.

Comment: Thank for your time. Could you please tell me how can i get the related_model_id? is it a name of the value? and  should i override the custom module or crate the new module that inherits the custom module?

Comment: Moreover, the field is not required as well

Comment: For the related_model_id I provided an example above. The `env['related.model']` you will replace with the model for your Many2one and the domain will be a query which should find the specific record you are looking for.

Comment: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html documents domains

Comment: Hi Phillip, i get it. actually, the many2one field is setted at sale.order.line object, could i follow the your method to set default value that depend the product is set the BOM or not? Meaning when the user set the product that come with BOM > the value of many2one filed will be set by default, if product does has the BOM > the many2one will not be set any value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lambda to set default:

```
type = fields.Many2one('your.model',"String to display", default=lambda self: self.env['your.model'].search([('name','=','value you need to set as default')]))
```